# How can i match this with ruby regex {{article | image}}

Tags: ruby, regex

It also needs to work for {{ article |image}} or any other withespace combination inside the double braces.

Comment: I should bee more spesific. The text Im searching contains html and some special stuff that Im searching for. This is for instance {{article.title}} which I have found a working regex for. However the {{article | image}} seems to be harder. It should also find {{ article|image}} {{article|image }} etc. but no other brace term such as {{article | whatever_other_than_image }}

Comment: `/^\{\{\s*article\s*|\s*image\s*\}\}$/` and `//` both match this string. What exactly do you need?

Comment: ended up using this /\{\{s*article+\s*\|\s*image+\s*\}\}/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a lot more information about exactly what you need and the type of data you are searching.

```
{{.*}}
```

This will work for both examples.

```
{{\s*\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*}}
```

Is much more specific.

Comment: `{{.*}}` will match this entire string: `{{abc}} nono {{def}}`; you should to use a non-greedy pattern, as `{{.*?}}`

Comment: thanks, this works. what should I replace in this regex to make in work for only {{article | image}} and not for {{article | something_else}}.

Comment: `{{\s*article\s*\|\s*image\s*}}` will do the trick; sad use for a regex

Answer (score 1):

This will match all your `{{ }}` content:

```
{{([^}]*)}}
```

Comment: {} are not metacharacters except when used as the {min,max} quantifier, so no need to escape them, especially not in the character class.